# Merge results from uniq -c

Tags: linux, merge, sorting, uniq

I have many files with results of command:
uniq -c some_file > some_file.out

For example:
1.out:

```
 1 a
 2 b
 4 c
```

2.out

```
 2 b
 8 c
```

I would like to merge these results, so I get:

```
 1 a
 4 b
 12 c
```

I thought that sort or uniq could handle it but I don't see any option related to it.
Writing some ruby/perl script is one of way to go but I'd like to do it easly with core *nix commands (like mentioned sort and uniq).

Edit:
To be clear. I don't have original files and I have to merge *.out files.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I guess there should be a solution involving only join, awk and expr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with `awk`:

```
awk '{ count[$2] += $1 } END { for(elem in count) print count[elem], elem }' 1.out 2.out
```

Comment: Ok, it should work for me. It's not ideal because I expect to do it with O(N) memory usage, where N is number of files but it will work for some time (unless I have big results). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's linear in the number of files because `awk` reads all files in sequence, one line at a time, and it only needs to keep the `count` array (hash table?) in memory.

Comment: I didn't say that solution given by Philipp is linear. I said that it can be written such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a specific problem, so it's unlikely any tool will do this by default. You can script it in a small enough loop (no need for awk nastyness), implemented in any scripting language (even sh). I don't think there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite serious (but it works). I like Philipps solution.

```
cat 1.out 2.out |
{
    while read line; do
        for i in $(seq ${line% *}); do
            echo ${line#* }
        done
    done
} | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for the specific values provided in the question. If the output of `uniq -c` contains more spaces than just the one between the count and the value however, the following `awk` script does not truncate output after the second field:

```
awk '{ cnt=$1; $1=""; count[substr($0, 2)] += cnt } END { for(elem in count) print count[elem], elem }' 1.out 2.out
```